# Django-cms ImportError: No module named sitescms

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-cms

I am trying install **[django-cms](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/how_to/install.html)**. But I got following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/savad/virtuals/kw/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/savad/virtuals/kw/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/savad/virtuals/kw/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 252, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/savad/virtuals/kw/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/savad/virtuals/kw/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/savad/virtuals/kw/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/savad/virtuals/kw/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 119, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named sitescms
```

I used django-cms==3.4.2 and django==1.8.17.

Comment: Can you please copy and paste your `INSTALLED_APPS` from your `settings.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like you're missing a comma in the list of your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

Could it be that it says

```
...,
'sites'
'cms',
...
```

instead of

```
...,
'sites',
'cms',
....
```

The missing comma results in `sitescms`.

Comment: Yeah.. my mistake. Thanks for your help.